# Matrix derivative and product rule

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

> Let $A$ be a square matrix with non-negative elements. Let $n$ be a positive integer. How to evaluate the following for all possible $n$?
>
> $$f_{n}(A, i, j) = \frac{\partial }{\partial A_{ij}}\left(\vec{1}A^{n}\vec{1}^{\intercal}\right)$$
>
> where $\vec{1}$ is a row vector and $\vec{1}^{\intercal}$ is transpose of $\vec{1}$.

**Attempt to solve**

I thought

$$f_{3}(A, i, j) =\vec{1}(BAA + ABA +AAB)\vec{1}^{\intercal}$$

where

$$B_{i'j'} = \begin{cases} 1, & i = i', j=j' \\ 0, &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

But the problem is that the expression is always non-negative.

Unless the function is monotonic, I would not expect the first derivative to always have the same sign.

What is the correct answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B={\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
makes the derivation a bit easier, but won't be needed in the final result.

Write the inner function in terms of this product.

Then find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= 1^TA^n1 = 11^T:A^n \cr
d\phi
 &= 11^T:dA^n \cr
 &= 11^T:\sum_{k=1}^{n} A^{k-1}\,dA\,A^{n-k} \cr
 &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \Big(A^{k-1}11^TA^{n-k}\Big)^T:dA \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial A} &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \Big(A^{k-1}11^TA^{n-k}\Big)^T \cr
}$$
To extract the $(i,j)^{th}$ element, multiply by the $(e_i,e_j)$ vectors from the standard basis 
$$\eqalign{
f_n(A,i,j)
 &= e_i^T\,\Big(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial A}\Big)\,e_j \cr
 &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} e_i^T\Big(A^{k-1}11^TA^{n-k}\Big)^Te_j \cr
 &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} e_j^T\,A^{k-1}11^TA^{n-k}\,e_i \cr
 &= \sum_{k=1}^{n} 1^TA^{n-k}\,e_ie_j^T\,A^{k-1}1 \cr
 &= 1^T\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{n} A^{n-k}\,e_ie_j^T\,A^{k-1}\bigg)1 \cr
}$$

Comment: Is $1$ a column vector? Does that mean what I did was actually correct? The $11^{T}$ looks like summing my $B$ over all $i$ and $j$.

Comment: Yes, $1$ is a column vector. I should have pointed out that change. Also $e_i$ is a column vector.

Comment: @hamsteronwheels I've re-arranged my answer to look more like your result.